# How to implement RAG with LLMs for a large collection of local PDF documents

Tags: pdf, openai-api, large-language-model

I am currently working on a project where I intend to utilize a LLM to provide answers to user inquiries, drawing from a substantial collection of local PDF documents. These documents are subject to daily updates, with approximately 10 new documents being added each day.

Could you suggest the most effective method and process for enabling the LLM to access and utilize information from these local documents?

I recognize that directly feeding all these documents into the LLM, such as ChatGPT, is not feasible.

Would it be advisable to first employ libraries to extract content (text, tables, charts) from the PDF documents? Should I then proceed to embed this information and store it in a vector database, subsequently utilizing vector database search to supply the necessary information to the LLM for generating responses?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector database storing all the documents (with a real-time pipeline that adds the new additions and indexes + generates embeddings for them too as they come in).

So when you want to create a new query - you would first retrieve any relevant documents from your dataset; then use this context to generate answers based on the relevant context.

You can read more about it on this blog from Elastic about Rag: https://www.elastic.co/what-is/retrieval-augmented-generation.

This part describes what you were hinting at:

> ### Retrieval
>
> - RAG starts with an input query. This could be a user's question or any piece of text that requires a detailed response.
> - A retrieval model grabs pertinent information from knowledge bases, databases, or external sources — or multiple sources at once. Where
>   the model searches depends on what the input query is asking. This
>   retrieved information now serves as the reference source for whatever
>   facts and context the model needs.
> - The retrieved information is converted into vectors in a high-dimensional space. These knowledge vectors are stored in a vector
>   database. The retrieval model ranks the retrieved information based on
>   its relevance to the input query. Documents or passages with the
>   highest scores are selected for further processing.
>
> ### Generation
>
> - Next, a generation model, such as an LLM, uses the retrieved information to generate text responses.
> - The generated text might go through additional post-processing steps to make sure it is grammatically correct and coherent.
> - These responses are, on the whole, more accurate and make more sense in context because they have been shaped by the supplemental
>   information the retrieval model has provided. This ability is
>   especially important in specialized domains where public internet data
>   is insufficient.

You can pick and choose which technologies you want to use for each part - could be openAI as an LLM for embeddings; elasticsearch for the actual search engine; probably LangChain to keep everything in one pipeline; etc.

Here's an example of a walkthrough for inspiration: https://www.elastic.co/search-labs/blog/articles/gen-ai-using-cohere-llm

Or this chatbot app example with multiple model options to choose from: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-labs/tree/main/example-apps/chatbot-rag-app

Hope this helps!